# Same table name for two JPA persistence units with NetBeans

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="first" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>database.first.entity.Grupe</class>
        <properties>
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://*****/first"/>
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*****"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="second" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>database.second.entity.Darbuotojas</class>
        <class>database.second.entity.Grupe</class>
        <properties>
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://*******/second"/>
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*****"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As you see there is one **Grupe** class in each persistence unit. But when I try to create two `@Entity` classes with same **Grupe** name (but in different packages, therefore this shouldn't be a problem) NetBeans gives me error:

```
Duplicated entity name. Class database.first.entity.Grupe is using the same name.
```

Is there any annotations witch could solve this problem, because I don't want to create classes with different class names like **GrupeFirst** and **GrupeSecond**.

Comment: What happens if you just ignore the error? Does your app work as expected, or does eclipselink complain?

Comment: @Minutis How did you even manage to get Netbeans to generate entity classes from two tables with the same name? I can only manage to UPDATE or RECREATE the class, even if they are in different packages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be ok if they are in different persistence units.

Try setting  to true, it might be finding both classes because they are in the same jar file.

Instead of renaming the class you can also just set the name on the @Entity to a different name.

Comment: It seems to be ok, I can just ignore that error. It's NetBeans bug.